# ntp server is not working correct at startup

Tags: networking, server, time, ntp

I use Ubuntu server 16.04 and I set up local NTP server with the following configs in `/etc/ntp.conf` file:

```
# this is the IP or name of the local networks NTP ser$
# should be commented out on the server
# server 192.168.1.202 iburst         # this line is uncommented for clients

# this enables checking the local clock. Do not change$
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 10

# this lines are required to run the ntpq -p command t$
# function of the system

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
```

The problem is when I restart the system, time is not synced and correct and even is wrong!
Output of the command `timedate status` in server:

```
Local time: Thu 2018-02-22 19:03:50 IRST
  Universal time: Thu 2018-02-22 15:33:50 UTC
        RTC time: Thu 2018-02-22 15:33:50
       Time zone: Asia/Tehran (IRST, +0330)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Here UTC time is the correct local time.
in the clients:

```
Local time: Mon 2018-02-19 02:07:18 IRST
  Universal time: Sun 2018-02-18 22:37:18 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2018-02-18 22:37:19
       Time zone: Asia/Tehran (IRST, +0330)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

In server machine the date is correct but the time is wrong. In client machine both are wrong.
The peers in clients are `ntpq -p`:

```
    remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 192.168.1.202    LOCAL(0)        11 u   46   64    1    0.381  3201920   0.011
*LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l   17   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

But when I use command `sudo apt update` date became correct in clients:

```
    Local time: Thu 2018-02-22 19:16:44 IRST
  Universal time: Thu 2018-02-22 15:46:44 UTC
        RTC time: Sun 2018-02-18 22:50:13
       Time zone: Asia/Tehran (IRST, +0330)
 Network time on: no
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

But time still is wrong! I used the command `date -s "correct time and date"`, but after restarting it goes wrong!

How can I fix the problem!

Comment: Can you include the output of `ntpq -p` and `echo rv | ntpq` on the server in your question?

Comment: @vidarlo The post contains `ntpq -p`

Comment: have you tried `timedatectl set-ntp 1` ? Also, it takes a few minutes until your machine is synchronized with the NTP server.

Comment: Yes, but it is not permanently. I want everything works correctly after rebooting, but everything becomes messy!

Comment: I was thinking of `ntpq -p` on the server, not the client. But it's not needed; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 192.168.1.202    LOCAL(0)        11 u   46   64    1    0.381  3201920   0.011
*LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l   17   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

This is the output of `ntpq -p` on the client, and it is essentially the answer to why the client does not sync. The client uses it's own clock as a stratum 10 reference - but the server claims it is stratum 11.

NTP treats lower stratum clocks as more likely to be correct. Here you have two time sources, one with stratum 11 and one with 10 - and a huge difference. It won't attempt to reconcile them - it will simply say that the stratum 11 one is wrong.

Set the server to a lower stratum, using the

```
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 9
```

for instance. Or - preferably sync the server to an external time source that is more reliable, for instance one of the NTP pools, which is generally stratum 1-3. Syncing to a stratum 3 NTP server would make your NTP server a stratum 4 NTP server, which would be preferred over the local clock.

Another alternative is to increase the stratum of your local clock on the clients, for instance to 13.

Comment: Thanks, Can you say why the time and date is wrong at the startup. I set them using the command `sudo date -s "MYTIME"` but after restarting it bach to the wrong time and date!!!

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/DateTime explains why.

Comment: I mean How can I set correct time, permanently

Comment: `sudo hwclock -w` will write it to the systems hardware clock. But it will hardly be permanent; clocks drift. That is why we have NTP. In addition, Ubuntu *should* write hwclock on shutdown...

Comment: My cluster is not connected to the network so I should set the server correct time manually. So you suggest using command `sudo hwclock -w` for that?

Comment: `hwclock -w` writes system time to hardware clock.

Comment: Okay. If your systems are not internet connected, set your servers reference clock to some rather low stratum, like 4-5, and your clients hardware clock to stratum 14-15.